# Foreach Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, foreach

Is it just me or it's my foreach loop is acting weird. I've made a foreach to check if there is a result fetched but if there isn't, I'd be showing a notice/text acknowledging the that there are now results found. The problem here is that,I won't show any text if it doesn't return anything. What seems to be the problem here?

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
     {{ Form::open(['url'=>'flight/onewayflightresults']) }}          
        <div>
            <p>Scheduled Flights</p>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-hover">
                    <th>Reserve</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>Departure</th>
                    <th>Adult</th>
                    <th>Children</th>
                    <th>Fare per person</th>
                    <th>Book Flight</th>
            @foreach($result as $row)
                @if(count($row) != 0)

                        <tr>
                            <td>{{Form::checkbox('reserve', 'value');}}</td>
                            <td>{{$row -> id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$row -> destinationfrom}}</td>
                            <td>{{$row -> destinationto}}</td>
                            <td>{{$row -> departure}}</td>
                            <td>{{{$adult}}}</td>
                            <td>{{{$child}}}</td>
                            <td>&#x20b1;{{{$row -> fare}}}</td>
                            <td>{{ Form::submit('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#10004;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',array('class'=>'btn btn-success')) }}</td>
                        </tr>       
                @else 
                    <p class="bg-danger">Sorry but we have no available flight schedule on your desidered date.</p>
                @endif 
            @endforeach
       </table>
     {{ Form::close() }}
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to count `$row`, while it is an object. I'm not sure, but perhaps you want to do this kind of logic instead?

```
@if (count($result))
    @foreach($result as $row)
        <!-- output rows -->
    @endforeach
@else
    <!-- output no flights found -->
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `forealse` construction:

```
@forelse($result as $row)
 <tr>
    {{-- here single row code -- }}
 </tr> 
@empty
     <p class="bg-danger">Sorry but we have no available flight schedule on your desidered date.</p>
@endforelse
```